# MongoDB - Grouping by inner-documents and retrieving top results

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find the most common (and least common) skills stored in the mongo database. I'm using mongoose to retrieve the results.

The `User` is the root document, which each have an inner `Profile` document. The profile has an attribute of 'skills' which contain an array of `ProfileSkillEntry`'s which has a `title` (the skill name).

```
return User.aggregate([{
        $group: {
            '_id': '$profile.skills.title',
            'count': {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }, {
        $sort: {
            'count': -1
        }
    }, {
        $limit: 5
    }]);
```

I expect it to combine all of the registered Users skills together, find the top 5 occurring and return that. Instead it seems to be grouping per-user and giving invalid results.

Example `User` document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "firstName" : "Harry",
    "lastName" : "Potter",
    "profile" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
        "skills" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
                "title" : "Java",
                "description" : "Master",
                "dateFrom" : "31/07/2019",
                "coreSkill" : true
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
                "title" : "JavaScript",
                "description" : "Proficient",
                "dateFrom" : "31/07/2019",
                "coreSkill" : false
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your document

Comment: @Anban Included example User document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below query. Just add the sort and limit as per your requirement

```
db.test.aggregate(
[{ $unwind: {  path: "$profile.skills"} }, 
{ $group: {  _id: "$profile.skills.title",  
    "count": {    $sum: 1  }} }] )
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.